# Should API calls & logic go in models or controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails app where I use many APIs like Google Adwords, Facebook Graph, etc.

Where should I call these APIs? In the models or in controllers?

Comment: Not really an answer, but I put it in the model if I have an appropriate one, and a controller if there isn't a corresponding model.  I figure model methods can be called anywhere and will help with the DRY thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use lib directory for these type of things. It is a clean and reusable way.

lib/facebook_api.rb

```
class FacebookApi
  def initialize(opts={})
    @token = "..."
    @type = opts[:type] || "me"
  end

  def call
    @response = Httparty.get("#{@type} #{@token}") #example not real.
    @response
  end
end
```

You can use it like

```
@facebook_api = FacebookApi.new(type: "friends")
@facebook_api.call
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is **Controller**..

We get results from API in **Controller** and we can store it in **model**.

First every action will done inside a controller .

And we may declare API path in **production.rb**. and use it anywhere inside a application. If need to change API path then just change it in production.rb.